# In what situations could an iCal VEVENT end up with a duplicated UID?

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I can't seem to figure out why these Google iCal events have a few non-unique UIDs. The [spec says that event UIDs "MUST" be unique](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.7), but Google Calendar is returning a few duplicates.

```
➜ grep 'UID:' testcal.ics | wc -l
744

➜ grep 'UID:' testcal.ics | uniq -c
738

➜ grep 'UID:' testcal.ics | uniq -d
UID:p7gllqg6177dj05omcc3cejl9o@google.com
UID:u64e5o1fm802dt5s4fn71perho@google.com
UID:q09i2hjd7nfavjc2j65e7o29qk@google.com
UID:6baas9neong05nrfca8lein2kl@google.com
```

`testcal.ics` is an export of one of my personal calendars which goes back about 10 years. The calendar has hundreds of events of all types. Recurring events that I created, events I was invited to, transparent events, multi-day events, etc. etc. etc.

The four UIDs listed above all correspond to recurring events. For each duplicated UID, there is a "parent" `VEVENT` which lists the recurring rule and a "child" `VEVENT` to represent an individual instance in that sequence. In one case, there are two instances and one "parent" which all share the same UID.

They don't seem to have any correlation beyond the fact that they are all recurring events. They have >=1 instances in the recurrence which *did* get a unique UID. Likewise, there are hundreds of other recurring events which are not affected by this. These four happened at very different times (2013, 2015, 2018 and 2020), so the device/app managing them would have been very different each time.

Is this just a persistent bug or is there a legitimate situation where duplicate UIDs might be appropriate (even if it isn't in the spec)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is legitimate to have multiple VEVENT with the same UID in a calendar stream. One is the master recurring event (it has either RRUle or RDATE properties), while the other ones have a RECURRENCE-ID and do corresponds to instances of the recurring event for which a change was made only to that instance (e.g. change of LOCATION).

See for example https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-4.4.8

Comment: Correct. If there is a RECURRENCE-ID, then it is a single instance of a recurring event that been modified separately from the main event (an exception).    Another reason you may see what looks like a duplicated UID is if the event itself has been modified (certain fields).  Then you will also have a SEQUENCE. https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-8-7-4-sequence-number.html.

Comment: This makes sense, but I would have expected to see more of these duplicated IDs then. There were lots of recurring events in that calendar, active and expired, but these four UIDs were the only duplicates in the lot. Do you know why it might duplicate the UID for some but not others?

Comment: It depends on the type of client you are using and your own usage pattern when it comes to modifying recurring events: some clients offer the ability to modify "Only that instance" or "All instances", or "All future instances", etc... while others just modify the master recurring event without asking. If using the later, or if you are most often selecting "All instances" when modifying such event, then you will end up with few of those recurring events with exceptions.